# best in place gem becomes editable only when clicked on the data , how to enable editing when the user clicks anywhere in that particular td

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I'm using the best in place gem for in-place editing in the table. It works great but the column field becomes editable only when clicked on the data. I want it to be editable when clicked anywhere in that column area.

Also how i can i give some styling to indicate the user that the column fields are editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by applying css to the best in place class provided by the method :)

Comment: Some additional information would be helpful. Perhaps include the relevant CSS?